# Run a Machine only if another machine is not working and Vice a Versa

Tags: anylogic

Below is my Model. I have machines M1 & M2.
[image: My Model]

Below is my use case;

- M1 must work, only when M2 is not working
- M2 must work, only when M1 is not working
- M1 & M2 can not operate at the same time

To achieve the above use case i wrote the below code with logic, if M2 is busy, i want to stop M1 and vice versa.

Code Block;

**"On Enter" of M1;**

*`if (M2.Busy()) { M1.suspend(); }`*

and

**"On Enter" of M2;**

*`if (M1.Busy())  { M2.suspend(); }`*

Unfortunately, the code ends up in the error, Busy() and Suspend() is undefined.

Any help on this will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of a queue use a wait block.

source->w1->m1->w2->m2

in w1 and w2 on enter

```
if(m2.size()==0 && m1.size()==0) w1.free(agent);
```

in m1 and m2 on at exit, assuming m2 is priority, otherwise change the order

```
if(w2.size()>0) w2.free(w2.get(0));
else if(w1.size()>0) w1.free(w1.get(0));
```

Comment: Hello Felipe, 
Thanks a lot! it worked! 
However, surprisingly in W2-  in the end, it holds 1 unit. 
I tried inducing forced pushing to push the last unit , but it did not work.  
then I also wrote a code line at exit of W2 and entry of M2 to push the last unit ; 
if (M1.size() == 0) w2.free(agent);
But it didn't work. It still holds one unit inside W2.  Any ideas what I am doing wrong?
(At source, i just had 5 arrivals, 1 per second)
Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello Felipe,
I resolved the Above issue with just a minor tweak below;
Source-W1-M1-W2-M2-Sink (w =wait, M= delay)
On enter, in W1 and W2  i wrote below code lines;

if (m1.size() ==0 && w1.size()==0) w2.free(agent);
else if(m2.size()==0 && m1.size()==0) w1.free(agent);

On at Exit in M1 and M2;
if(w2.size()>0) w2.free(w2.get(0));
else if (w1.size()>0) w1.free(w1.get(0));

Thanks for the all the suggestions and help Felipe!

Answer (score 0):

Source-W1-M1-W2-M2-Sink (w =wait, M= delay) On enter, in W1 and W2 i wrote below code lines;

`if (m1.size() ==0 && w1.size()==0) w2.free(agent);`

`else if(m2.size()==0 && m1.size()==0) w1.free(agent);`

On at Exit in M1 and M2;

`if(w2.size()>0) w2.free(w2.get(0));`

`else if (w1.size()>0) w1.free(w1.get(0));`

Credits;
Thanks to felipe for all the suggestions and help.